# How to migrate requiring of select2.js from sprockets to webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, jquery-select2, es6-modules

I'm in the process of migrating a Rails 5.1.5 project, which uses CoffeeScript, from using sprockets to using webpacker. The project also uses `select2.js`. With sprockets, I did the following:

1. Install `jquery-rails` (jQuery is a dependency for `select2`).
2. Put `select2.js` code in `vendor/assets/javscripts`.
3. In `application.js.coffee`, add:

   ```
   #= require select2
   ```

After that I was able to use select2 to in my `application.js.coffee` file:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load' ->
  $('select').select2
```

So far I've described the pretty standard way of including/using javascript libraries with sprockets.

However, with webpacker I can't make select2 work and I'm not sure why. I have two hypothesis:

- I'm not importing/requiring it properly;
- it doesn't find jQuery at some point of the load process;

So for jQuery, I did the following:

- `yarn add jquery`
- included in my `environment.js`:

  ```
  const webpack = require('webpack');

  environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  }));
  ```

I've removed the `jquery-rails` gem, as well as `#= require 'jquery'` and tested that jquery works, so I guess I have correctly included it. However, I tried several ways of importing `select2` (using es6 imports) and none of them worked. I tried:

```
import select2 from 'select2';
import select2 from 'select2/dist/js/select2'
import select2 from 'select2/dist/js/select2.js'
import 'select2/dist/js/select2.js'
```

I even tried to import it from the old `vendor location` by writing inside `app/javascript/pack/application.js.coffee`:

```
import '../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/select2'
```

I can confirm that the file contents is imported, as I put a console.log within the select2 file under `node_modules/select2/dist/js/select.js` and it did get printed. However, I also get the error `TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function` when I execute `$('select').select2()` in the browser's dev tool console.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

P.S. I can provide much more info, but I didn't want my question to get any more bloated.
P.P.S. With my modest JS knowledge, I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/develop/dist/js/select2.js) but couldn't recognize what exactly they are exporting and how am I supposed to import it.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but just in case someone else could benefit:

**app/javascript/packs/application.js**

```
...other requires...
require('select2')

window.Rails = Rails

import 'bootstrap'
...other imports...
import 'select2'
import 'select2/dist/css/select2.css'

$(document).on("turbolinks:load", () => {
  $('.select2').select2()
})
```

Answer (score 2):

**My similar problem**

I have stumble upon the same problem with another web component ([Switchery](http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/)):

- I imported the component with `yarn add switchery` (no error)
- I could import it correctly through WebPack with `import 'switchery'` (no error bundling the pack)

But when I was trying to use the Switchery object in the browser like they say in the doc:

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.js-switch');
var init = new Switchery(elem);
```

I would get the error: `ReferenceError: Switchery is not defined`

Note: I didn't want to install RequireJS as WebPack is supposed to do the same thing (and even better) nowadays.

**My solution:**

The problem was the *webpack doesn't expose the pack-generated variables and classes in the global scope!*

So to fix this, I needed to do two things:

- Explicitly give a name to the imported class from Switchery:
  `import Switchery from 'switchery'`
- Use this Class only in the same JS file where the import was done

**Testing hack:**

If you want to try that out and "go back" to the mess that sprocket allowed, in the same file, you can expose "globally" the variable so you can use in from the browser:

```js
import Switchery from 'switchery'

window.Switchery = Swicthery
```

now you can execute the switchery almost like in the example:
`var init = new window.Switchery(elem);`

Hope that helps...